# C: Is there a way to define a macro AND output some code in a single statement?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I would like to define a macro that would generate program text for me AND also set some **non-string** macro value. I know that including `#define` in another `#define` is not going to work so I'm trying to find a different way.

A simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define START_SYNTHETIC int SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION() {
#define END_SYNTHETIC return 0;}


#define SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION my_function

START_SYNTHETIC
    printf("Hello from %s", "SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION");
END_SYNTHETIC


int main() {
    my_function();
}
```

This code kinda works, it produces the following output:

```
Hello from SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION
```

There are two problems with it:

1. function name is not expanded and I just have "SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION" in the output. This is currently not critical but might be needed later on.
2. I dislike having three lines to start my synthetic function. The empty line inserted by autoformatter is especially irritating. Can I reduce this to just a single macro invocation?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to define a macro AND output some code in a single statement?

No, in C macros can't define other macros.

> function name is not expanded and I just have "SYNTHETIC_FUNCTION" in the output.

Sure it doesn't - it's inside a string literal. Macro replacement is not done inside a string literal.

> Can I reduce this to just a single macro invocation?

I do not understand the point at all of this code. Just [use `__func__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/function_definition#func).

```
int my_function(void) {
    printf("Hello from %s\n", __func__);
    return 0;
}
```

or pass the name as a macro parameter:

```
#define SYNTHETIC(name) \
int name(void) { \
    printf("Hello from %s\n", #name); \
    printf("but really, just use __func__ anyway...: %s\n", __func__); \
    return 0; \
}

SYNTHETIC(my_function)
```